# Drawing point geometry with StreamGeometryContext

Tags: c#, wpf, math, gis

Trying to draw a polar type chart using GeometryContext in C#. I have input of direction as an `xRange` (start & stop) which is in degrees. I'm converting this to Radians. All good. The `yRange` is cut in & cut out wind speed currently in m/s as a double. I'm trying to acheive a simplified version of the image below without the axis labels etc.

[image]

For each object to be charted I am returning an XY range:

```
 public IEnumerable<Styled2DRange> Query()
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Maroon);
        brush.Freeze();
        Pen linePen = new Pen(brush, 3);
        linePen.Freeze();
        SolidColorBrush fillBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Maroon);
        fillBrush.Freeze();

        foreach (var range in this.Charts)
        {
            Range xRange = new Range(ConvertToRadians(range.StartDirection), ConvertToRadians(range.EndDirection));
            Range yRange = new Range(range.CutInWindSpeed, range.CutOutWindSpeed);

            yield return new 2DRange()
            {
                Range = new XYRange()
                {
                    XRange = xRange,
                    YRange = yRange
                },

                Line = linePen,
                Fill = fillBrush
            };
        }

        yield break;
    }
```

This method is called from my override of `Onrender`. Obviously my points to be drawn by the `StreamGeometryContext` don't make sense as the Range.Y values are just wind speeds in m/s:

```
  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {             
         Point origin = new Point(0, 0);
         double maxR = 0;

         SweepDirection outerSweep = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
         SweepDirection innerSweep = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;

         outerSweep = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
         innerSweep = SweepDirection.Clockwise;

         foreach (Styled2DRange range in Query())
         {
             maxR = Math.Max(maxR, range.Range.YRange.End);

                Point outerScreenPointBefore = new    Point(range.Range.XRange.Start, range.Range.YRange.End);
                Point outerScreenPointAfter = new Point(range.Range.XRange.End, range.Range.YRange.End);

                Point innerScreenPointBefore = new Point(range.Range.XRange.Start, range.Range.YRange.Start);
                Point innerScreenPointAfter = new Point(range.Range.XRange.End, range.Range.YRange.Start);

                StreamGeometry sectorGeometry = new StreamGeometry();
                sectorGeometry.FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero;

                using (StreamGeometryContext geometryContext = sectorGeometry.Open())
                {

                    geometryContext.BeginFigure(innerScreenPointBefore, true, true);
                    geometryContext.LineTo(outerScreenPointBefore, true, false);

                    double outerCircleRadius = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(outerScreenPointBefore.X - origin.X, 2) + Math.Pow(outerScreenPointBefore.Y - origin.Y, 2));
                    geometryContext.ArcTo(outerScreenPointAfter, new Size(outerCircleRadius, outerCircleRadius), 0, false, outerSweep, true, false);

                    geometryContext.LineTo(innerScreenPointAfter, true, false);

                    double innerCircleRadius = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(innerScreenPointBefore.X - origin.X, 2) + Math.Pow(innerScreenPointBefore.Y - origin.Y, 2));
                    geometryContext.ArcTo(innerScreenPointBefore, new Size(innerCircleRadius, innerCircleRadius), 0, false, innerSweep, true, false);
                }

                sectorGeometry.Freeze();
                dc.DrawGeometry(range.Fill, range.Line, sectorGeometry);
            }
       }
```

So how do I reference the wind speed to create an actual point within the bounds of the drawing?

Answer (score 1):

The four points of your chart sector are lying on two concentric circles, where the radius of the inner circle is given by the start wind speed, and that of the outer circle by the end wind speed. The position of the points on each circle is directly given by the wind directions in radians.

Provided that you have the variables `startDirection` and `endDirection` for the wind directions and `startSpeed` and `endSpeed` for the wind speeds, a sector would be constructed like this:

```
var pStart = new Point(Math.Sin(startDirection), -Math.Cos(startDirection));
var pEnd = new Point(Math.Sin(endDirection), -Math.Cos(endDirection));
var isLargeArc = Math.Abs(endDirection - startDirection) > Math.PI;
var geometry = new StreamGeometry();

using (var sgc = geometry.Open())
{
    sgc.BeginFigure( // start point on inner circle
        new Point(startSpeed * pStart.X, startSpeed * pStart.Y),
        true, true);

    sgc.ArcTo( // end point on inner circle
        new Point(startSpeed * pEnd.X, startSpeed * pEnd.Y),
        new Size(startSpeed, startSpeed), // radius of inner circle
        0d, isLargeArc, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, true);

    sgc.LineTo( // end point on outer circle
        new Point(endSpeed * pEnd.X, endSpeed * pEnd.Y),
        true, true);

    sgc.ArcTo( // start point on outer circle
        new Point(endSpeed * pStart.X, endSpeed * pStart.Y),
        new Size(endSpeed, endSpeed), // radius of outer circle
        0d, isLargeArc, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, true);
}
```